# is it ok to have asynchronous functions handling request?

Tags: node.js, express, azure-cosmosdb

The most of my http requests perform database operations which are asynchronous, so the most of them look like this :

```
myRouter.post('/groups', (req, res, next) => {
  groupsController.createGroup(req, res).catch(next);
})
```

and inside the the controller I will await the db response before responding like this :

```
 exports.createGroup = async function(req,res){
        var group = req.body.group;
        // retrieving the database object and performing the asyncrhonous action 
        group = await req.app.get('db').createGroup(group);
        res.status(201).json(group);
    }
```

I'm using cosmos db and as far as I know all operations are async, is it correct to do this ?

Comment: It's ok. The separation between a 'controller' and route handler isn't justified, It could be a single function. There's no specific entity as controller in Express.

Answer (score 2):

Well no if you don't want to block your controller.

Your controller should just pass the results back to route handler, where you would in `.then()` promise handler process result and send response.

Personally (not sure if this is practice is node/javascript design patterns, i like to separate concerns between request handler and (data, service...) controller - meaning handler will extract data from the request, make a call to controller and construct http response based on the result. I would be sending HTTP responses back from the controller

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is the correct way of doing things when you are building a server. All the I/O operations like communicating with db/network/disk etc. must be asynchronous.